# Фразеологізм "Накрити мокрим рядном" - архаїзм?

Tags: фразеологізми, архаїзми

Фразеологізм є досить складним і його важко зрозуміти, це нам повідомляє сайт [Dovidka](http://dovidka.biz.ua).

На цьому ж сайті [наведені приклади вживання](http://dovidka.biz.ua/mokrim-ryadnom-nakriti-znachennya/) цього вислову

> Вона на мене мокрим рядном, що стільки грошей перевів (Борис Грінченко, I, 1963, 480);
>   Він так на дочку обрушився, як мокрим рядном накрив (Грицько Григоренко, Вибр., 1959, 248);
>   Килина так і вкрила мокрим рядном Зарубу за те, що на фермах і досі немає усіх машин (Василь Кучер, Трудна любов, 1960, 482);
>   Батько знов накрив її мокрим рядном.— І де ти в іродового батька волочишся! (І. Нечуй-Левицький);
>   — Повертайте, хлопці, сьогоднішній виторг! — одразу ж накрив мокрим рядном своїх вірних помічників (М. Стельмах);
>   Не доведи Боже Галі що лишнє сказати, лишній раз устати, по хаті пройти — так мати і вкриє мокрим рядном (Панас Мирний);

Чи буде доречним назвати цей фразеологізм архаїзмом, адже він використаний лише у літературі ХХ століття?

Answer (score 3):

"адже він використаний лише у литературі ХХ століття?"

Василь Слапчук, "[Книга забуття](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=25903)" (2013):

> ... хрипкий голос капітана Нефьодова владно здійнявся над їхніми головами і знагла упав, наче мокрим  рядном накрив.

Володимир Лис, "[Камінь посеред саду](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=32727)" (2015):

> Одного прекрасного дня він усіх нас накриє    мокрим  рядном або просто відкриє, що хитрував, отже, був розумнішим за нас.

Юрій Винничук, "[Танго смерті](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=33789)" (2012):

> пані Конопелька за цей час ледь яйце не знесла, вона напустилася на
>   мене з    мокрим  рядном і збештала, що я такий пан Ґуздральський *

Отже, ні, використаний цей фразеолоґізм не лише у літературі 20 ст.

До того всього маємо статтю на СУМ-11:

> Мокрим рядном на кого — зненацька, несподівано (звичайно
>   приголомшувати лайкою, докором і т. ін.). Іван Петрович до секретаря,
>   а секретар — мокрим рядном на Івана Петровича (Панас Мирний, I, 1954,
>   156);

І пояснення на досить-таки сучасному сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/nakrutu-mokrum-ryadnom):

> Накрити мокрим рядном - вилаяти.